# linearGradientProps crashes my app

Tags: react-native

What can I do about it? I can't use the code that should work:

```
<Button
                        text="SIGNUP"
                        ViewComponent={require('react-native-linear-gradient').LinearGradient}
                        linearGradientProps={{
                            colors: ['red', 'pink', 'red'],
                        }}
                    />
```

I get this annoyance:

```
console.error: "You need to pass a ViewComponent to use linearGradientProps !
Example: ViewComponent={require('react-native-linear-gradient')}"
error
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:53482:18
componentDidMount
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:75816:24
proxiedComponentDidMount
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:35849:47
commitLifeCycles
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:9162:47
commitAllLifeCycles
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:10328:31
invokeGuardedCallback
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2741:21
invokeGuardedCallback
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2810:40
commitRoot
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:10408:38
completeRoot
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:11329:52
performWorkOnRoot
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:11286:29
performWork
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:11219:32
performSyncWork
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:11200:22
requestWork
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:11127:28
scheduleWorkImpl
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:11000:28
scheduleWork
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:10960:34
enqueueSetState
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:6796:25
setState
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:23663:37
dispatch
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:63019:27
navigate
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:63414:37
_handlePageChanged
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:70273:28
_jumpToIndex
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:70760:35
_handleOnPress
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:72995:22
_handleTabPress
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:72256:32
onPress
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:72058:52
_callTimer
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:15395:17
callTimers
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:15600:19
__callFunction
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2368:49
<unknown>
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2138:31
__guardSafe
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2330:13
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2137:21
```

It seems to be the same issue as this one https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/issues/873

my settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'koolbusiness'
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
include ':react-native-linear-gradient'
project(':react-native-linear-gradient').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/android')
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
include ':react-native-share'
project(':react-native-share').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-share/android')
include ':react-native-image-picker'
project(':react-native-image-picker').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker/android')
include ':@remobile/react-native-splashscreen'
project(':@remobile/react-native-splashscreen').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@remobile/react-native-splashscreen/android')

include ':app'
```

my app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.koolbusiness"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 56
        versionName "0.0.56a"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
     signingConfigs {
            release {
                if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                    storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                    storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                    keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                    keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
                }
            }
        }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-share')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

With RNE beta2 instead of beta3 the error message is:

```
ViewManager: Error while updating prop end
                                                                       java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:107)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:154)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:58)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:298)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:289)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:364)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:374)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:162)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194)
                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeArray cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getDouble(ReadableNativeMap.java:148)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.DynamicFromMap.asDouble(DynamicFromMap.java:66)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode$MutableYogaValue.setFromDynamic(LayoutShadowNode.java:57)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode.setPositionValues(LayoutShadowNode.java:672)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:107) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:154) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:58) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:298) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:289) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:364) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:374) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:162) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194) 
                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
03-29 16:18:49.640 10793-10822/com.koolbusiness E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
                                                                       com.facebook.react.bridge.JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException: Error while updating property 'end' in shadow node of type: RCTView
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:113)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:154)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:58)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:298)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:289)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:364)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:374)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:162)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194)
                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:107)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:154) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:58) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:298) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:289) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:364) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:374) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:162) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194) 
                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeArray cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getDouble(ReadableNativeMap.java:148)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.DynamicFromMap.asDouble(DynamicFromMap.java:66)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode$MutableYogaValue.setFromDynamic(LayoutShadowNode.java:57)
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode.setPositionValues(LayoutShadowNode.java:672)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:107) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:154) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:58) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:298) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:289) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:364) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:374) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:162) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194) 
                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
03-29 16:18:49.711 10793-10793/com.koolbusiness D/ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.destroy() start
```

Comment: are you using https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient?

Comment: @wdlax11 Yes I try to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `require('react-native-linear-gradient').default`.
I've updated the example on Github, my bad.

Try this instead (with RNE `v1.0.0-beta3`):

```
<Button
  title="SIGNUP"
  ViewComponent={require('react-native-linear-gradient').default}
  linearGradientProps={{
    colors: ['#FF9800', '#F44336'],
    start: [1, 0],
    end: [0.2, 0],
  }}
/>
```

This should give you this result

[image: Button]

Answer (score 0):

Give something like this a try? this is their documented example on their github

```
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

// Within your render function
<LinearGradient colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']} style={styles.linearGradient}>
  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
    Sign in with Facebook
  </Text>
</LinearGradient>

// Later on in your styles..
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  linearGradient: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingRight: 15,
    borderRadius: 5
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontFamily: 'Gill Sans',
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    color: '#ffffff',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
});
```

Comment: It says in the docs linearGradientProps is only supported in expo so I give up. But the developers seem to mean it should work outside expo: https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/issues/873

Comment: I suggest you go here : https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient#manually and manually do the install for IOS.  I bet there is something messed up with the gradient install.  Try running my code above if that works then you know your gradient is installed correctly.  If not then you know thats the issue.  If that works we can move onto the next potential problem.  I've had problems with the lib before and the issue was the install wasn't done correctly

Comment: I use Android. I think that I can verify the installation. I think I tried everything. I updated the question with my settings and build files.

Comment: What about for part 3 of android install ? and finally, in android/src/main/java/com/{YOUR_APP_NAME}/MainActivity.java for react-native < 0.29, or android/src/main/java/com/{YOUR_APP_NAME}/MainApplication.java for react-native >= 0.29 add: the code they display on their site. the parts with <- THIS! next to it need to be added

Comment: Yes I checked it, will doublecheck it again and check your code again. _linearGradientProperties_ crashed my app complaining about _linearGradientProperties_ not passing a ViewComponent.

Comment: This code crashes: `<Button
  text="SIGNUP"
  ViewComponent={require('react-native-linear-gradient').LinearGradient}
  linearGradientProps={{
    colors: ['#FF9800', '#F44336'],
    start: [1, 0],
    end: [0.2, 0],
  }}
/>`

Comment: are you using the beta v1.0.0 version?

Comment: "react-native-elements": "^1.0.0-beta3",

Comment: try using beta 2 vs beta 3

Comment: I reinstalled everything and it is not working. Used `"react-native-elements": "^1.0.0-beta2",` maybe it should have been `"react-native-elements": "1.0.0-beta2",`

Comment: check to see in npm what version is installed - npm list or npm list package name.  make sure it says 1.0.0-beta2

Comment: it is beta2 installed. it crashes. It is the same problem as in this issue https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/issues/873

Comment: beta2 vs beta3 seems to generate different types of exceptions. beta2 is InvocationTargetException.